# Kaspersky AV is slowing down my connection significantly

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, anti-virus, kaspersky

I'm using Kaspersky AV 2010, and I've noticed recently in Firefox (DownThemAll download manager) that my download speed has been significantly reduced after installing Kaspersky (from 450 kb/s to 30 kb/s!!).

I can solve the issue temporarily by pausing protection and then resuming it again. But it's getting frustrating since I have to do this every few hours.

Also another issue I have with the AV (which could be related) is that it forces all network traffic to go through it! (Nod32 didnt do that).

Any idea what could be causing this?

Your help is much appreciated

Comment: i don´t use kaspersky av 2010 so i just can assume, that you can configure it? i´m using avast free antivirus and there you can configure which files are scanned and which files aren´t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be because it's scanning the files while their downloading. KAV uses some kind of network interface driver to tap into the nic itself.

I've been using KAV 2010 for about a year now and I don't like it. They've gotten much slower, it feels more bloated, and it slows down your system.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the given application to a whitelist/exception. Honeslty, KAV was **always** like this. A resource hog, but it is really tough. (You can reduce the protection levels and so on in the configuration dialogs.)

NOD32 is NOT protecting you against the internet stuff (at least not in every aspect). You have to buy/use the Smart Security version then which is designed for that purpose.

---

Personally I use Avast! Internet Security and I found it really fast. Comes with better protection than NOD (at least here it outperformed nod, don't want to start a flamewar or anything) and its much faster than Kaspersky. Finally I don't have to pause my protection if I want to play (because it won't add even 3ms to my latency) and it lets me use my full internet speed, its not even noticable.

If your license is getting old, try out Avast or something else. Every AV solution can be downloaded in trial and 30 day is more than enough. If you bought it recently (your license), live with it because it costs a fortune ^^". (There is a promotion at Avast, you can get 2 year for 1 year's price, I renewed my license in that pack.)